# Youtube API - Get notes from videos?

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-javascript-api

Im using Youtube api v3, I want to get the notes from videos in my playslist for example:

[image]

The screenshot above is from a playlist I have in my account - I want to get that note for each video in my playlist.

Ive hit `playlists` endpoint:
`youtube/v3/playlists&part=snippet&playlistId=${ID_HERE}&key=${KEY_HERE}`

and `playlistItems` endpoint:
`youtube/v3/playlistItems&part=snippet&playlistId=${ID_HERE}&key=${KEY_HERE}`

Neither return the notes in my videos! - Is this possible using this API ?

Currently responses look like this:

[image]

^ You can see there is no notes property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out:

You need to hit: 
`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet,contentDetails&playlistId=${PLAYLIST_ID}&key=${API_KEY}`

Note the part parameter is `snippet, contentDetails`

See: 
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems#contentDetails

Returns:

[image]